# How to change pgpool role automatically when pg_role changes after patroni cluster switchover leader?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, patroni

I try to use pgpool-II as loadbalancer to distribute select queries to replica and other dml queries to leader in my patroni cluster. After switchover on Patroni cluster, pgpool can not recognize leader node however pg_role status could be changed.

```
[root@ahimopostgres pgpool-II]# patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni1.yml list
^[[A+ Cluster: pg16stb (7337962854972656871) -+-----------+----+-----------+
| Member   | Host               | Role    | State     | TL | Lag in MB |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+----+-----------+
| pg16stb1 | 192.168.1.241:5432 | Replica | streaming | 11 |         0 |
| pg16stb2 | 192.168.1.241:5433 | Leader  | running   | 11 |           |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+----+-----------+
[root@ahimopostgres pgpool-II]# psql -h 192.168.1.241 -p 9999 -c "show pool_nodes;" -U postgres
 node_id |   hostname    | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+---------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | 192.168.1.241 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | standby | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-02-21 16:56:27
 1       | 192.168.1.241 | 5433 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | primary | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-02-21 16:56:27
(2 rows)

[root@ahimopostgres pgpool-II]# patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni1.yml list
+ Cluster: pg16stb (7337962854972656871) -+-----------+----+-----------+
| Member   | Host               | Role    | State     | TL | Lag in MB |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+----+-----------+
| pg16stb1 | 192.168.1.241:5432 | Replica | streaming | 11 |         0 |
| pg16stb2 | 192.168.1.241:5433 | Leader  | running   | 11 |           |
+----------+--------------------+---------+-----------+----+-----------+
```

In logs, i got

> sr_check_worker pid 21800: HINT:  BACKEND Error: "recovery is in
> progress"

What should i add to my pgpool.conf file to detect leader's changes automatically?

```
# Listen on all IP addresses
listen_addresses = '*'
pid_file_name  = '/var/run/pgpool-II/pgpool.pid'

# Port for Pgpool-II to listen on
port = 9999

# Number of child processes to fork
num_init_children = 32

# Number of connection pools to create per child process
max_pool = 4

# Log destinations
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_connections = on
log_hostname = on
logdir = '/var/log/pgpool-II'

# Authentication settings
enable_pool_hba = on
pool_passwd = '/etc/pgpool-II/passwd'
authentication_timeout = 30
ssl = off

# Health check settings
health_check_period = 10
health_check_timeout = 20
health_check_user = 'postgres'
health_check_password = 'postgres'
health_check_database = 'postgres'
health_check_max_retries = 3
health_check_retry_delay = 5

# Backend definitions for Patroni-managed PostgreSQL cluster
backend_hostname0 = '192.168.1.241'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1

backend_hostname1 = '192.168.1.241'
backend_port1 = 5433
backend_weight1 = 1

# Load balancing settings
load_balance_mode = on

## Failover settings
failover_command = '/etc/pgpool-II/failover %d %H %R'
failback_command = '/etc/pgpool-II/failback %d %H %R'

# SR mode
sr_check_user = 'postgres'
sr_check_password = 'postgres'
sr_check_database = 'postgres'

# Configure failover and load balancing
enable_query_cache = on
replication_mode = on
failover_when_quorum_exists = off
```